# Como corrigir o erro: HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception?

Tags: java, aplicação-web, eclipse, tomcat

Linguagem: Java
Servidor: Apache Tomcat.
Ambiente: Eclipse.

Estou seguindo a Apostila da Caelum do curso FJ21 - Desenvolvimento Web com Java. Criei um formulário mas na hora de gravar apresenta o seguinte erro:

> **HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception**
>
> type Exception report
>
> message Servlet execution threw an exception
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>   root cause
>
> java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>     Unhandled exception type SQLException
>
> br.com.caelum.jdbc.dao.ContatoDAO.(ContatoDAO.java:19)
>
> > br.com.caelum.agenda.servlet.AdicionaContatoServlet.service(AdicionaContatoServlet.java:46)
> >       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
> >       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> >     note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M15 logs.

Segue o código da classe ContatoDAO:

```
public class ContatoDAO {
  private Connection connection;

  public ContatoDAO()  {
    try {
      this.connection = new ConnectionFactory().getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void adiciona(Contato contato)  {
      String sql = "insert into contatos (nome, email, endereco, dataNascimento) values (?,?,?,?)";

      try {
        PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

        stmt.setString(1, contato.getNome());
        stmt.setString(2, contato.getEmail());
        stmt.setString(3, contato.getEndereco());
        stmt.setDate(4, new Date(contato.getDataNascimento().getTimeInMillis()));

        stmt.execute();
        stmt.close();
      } catch (SQLException e)  {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
  }
}
```

Classe Contato:

```
public class Contato {
  private Long id;
  private String nome;
  private String email;
  private String endereco;
  private Calendar dataNascimento;
  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }
  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  public String getNome() {
    return nome;
  }
  public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
  }
  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }
  public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
  }
  public String getEndereco() {
    return endereco;
  }
  public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
    this.endereco = endereco;
  }
  public Calendar getDataNascimento() {
    return dataNascimento;
  }
  public void setDataNascimento(Calendar dataNascimento) {
    this.dataNascimento = dataNascimento;
  }
}
```

Comment: Posta a classe "Contato"

Comment: Atualizei o post com a classe contato.

Answer (score 1):

A JVM está acusando que a exceção SQLException não está sendo tratada em algum dos métodos da sua classe ContatoDAO:

> java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: Unhandled exception
>   type SQLException

porém,o código que você postou parece ok. Pode ser que o código que está implantado no servidor está com erro e a IDE não tenha feito hotdeploy. Verifique novamente o seu código para ter certeza de que não existe erro de sintaxe e faça um build limpo do seu código. De preferência, exclua o .war do servidor e faça um build limpo e um redeploy completo.